# Bindings are not updated after setting DataContext in MvvmCross 4

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

After updating to MvvmCross 4.2 (from 3.5) we got a new bug in our app.

It's caused because of a binding in one of table cells:

```
_wrapper = new Wrapper(this) {Item = null};
this.DelayBind(() =>
    {
        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MyCell, MyCellViewModel>();
        set.Bind(_wrapper).For(w => w.Item).To(vm => vm);
        set.Apply();
    });
```

We have some complex binding logic in `Item` setter of `Wrapper`.
After upgrading to MvvmCross 4.2 the `Item` setter is called only once on first table load. Subsequent calls to `ReloadTableData()` (causing setting `DataContext` of the cell) don't cause calling `Item` setter.

Why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Does you _wrapper execute a RaisePropertyChanged() after being modified?

Comment: @hugo _wrapper.Item is a target of binding. MyCellViewModel is the source. So why does this matter?

Comment: I opened an issue in the MVVMCross github that might be related https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/1409

Comment: @yairsz already using old MvxBindingContext. it's not an issue here.